# Babel 7 spread syntax in IE/Edge not working

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, babeljs, ecmascript-2016, spread-syntax

So i have babel 7 installed, along with the plugin "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread" included within my preset-env, however I'm still getting the following error as it hasn't transpiled my spread operators back into es2015.

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
```

I've tried referencing the plugin in the plugin array within my .babelrc file.

My .babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-env", {
            "include": [
                "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
    ]
}
```

My package.json dependencies/dev dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.3",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "get-base64": "^1.3.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "qs": "^6.5.2",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-debounce-input": "^3.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^6.7.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-select": "^2.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack": "^4.23.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "interpolate-html-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "uglify-es-webpack-plugin": "^0.10.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're using Webpack, and you have `babel-loader` installed.

That being the case, here are two quick things to check:

- Are you sure you're using that loader in your webpack config for js files?

```
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
```

- Are there any js assets bypassing Webpack, "missing out" on that loader?
- (Edit): And if "no" to those, might you also need `"@babel/plugin-transform-spread"` to capture spreads in an array, since `"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"` is object-specific?

Comment: it was exactly this. Turns out the parts that weren't working were .js files, as my webpack was only testing jsx! thanks for this

Comment: I just want to add that this was what I was missing in my webpack configuration. Cost me three hours.